# 'dict' object has no attribute 'mean'. Problems using statistics.mean(list with numbers)

Tags: python

I am trying something new with flask, Python and the arduino. I want to measure things with the arduino, calculate and save some values through phyton and put it on display through flask.

Right now I can make sure that the arduino receives and gives information and the displaying to a localhost worked. However I want to calculate the average of a list that contain numbers (ints, floats and doubles)

However when I try to use `statistics.mean(recorded_humidities)` or any other recorded_ list I get hit with a error which is:

```
app.py, line 63, in greenhouse_dashboard
average_humidity = statistics.mean(recorded_humidities) 
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'mean'`
```

I can make a list in a seperate file, fill in some random numbers and then I can use the `statistics.mean(list_name)` just fine

I am confused what is happening here and I do not know what I can do or did wrong so I am hoping to find a answer here.

Here is the full code where values get calculated:

```
import statistics
import sensor

from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

from datetime import datetime

statistics = {}
recorded_humidities = []
recorded_temperatures = []
recorded_klux = []

minimal_humidites = 0
minimal_temperatures = 0
minimal_klux = 0

max_humidites = 0
max_temperatures = 0
max_klux = 0

average_humidity = 0
average_temperatures = 0
average_klux = 0

def current_time():
    rightNow = datetime.now()
    time = rightNow.strftime("%d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S")
    time = time.lstrip('0')
    time = time.lower()
    day = rightNow.strftime("%A")

    return "It is " + time + " on a " + day + "."

def current_humidity():
    humidity = sensor.humidity 
    return humidity

def current_temperature():
    temperature = sensor.temperature
    return temperature

def current_klux():
    klux = sensor.klux
    return klux

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def greenhouse_dashboard():
    recorded_humidities.append(current_humidity())
    recorded_temperatures.append(current_temperature())
    recorded_klux.append(current_klux())

#current values
#statistics["current_time"] = current_time()
#statistics["current_klux"] = current_klux()
#statistics["current_temperature"] = current_temperature()
#statistics["current_humidity"] = current_humidity()

#average values
average_humidity = statistics.mean(recorded_humidities) #fake value
average_temperatures = 2 #goes wrong
average_klux = 3 #goes wrong

#max values
max_humidites = max(recorded_humidities)
max_temperatures = max(recorded_temperatures)
max_klux = max(recorded_klux)

#min values
minimal_humidites = min(recorded_humidities)
minimal_temperatures = min(recorded_temperatures)
minimal_klux = min(recorded_klux)

return render_template('general.html',
                        time = current_time(),
                        humidity = current_humidity(),
                        temperature = current_temperature(),
                        klux = current_klux(),
                        average_klux = average_klux,
                        average_temperature = average_temperatures,
                        average_humidity = average_humidity,
                        min_klux = minimal_klux,
                        min_temperature = minimal_temperatures,
                        min_humidity = minimal_humidites,
                        max_klux = max_klux,
                        max_temperature = max_temperatures,
                        max_humidity = max_humidites)
```

I barely use stackoverflow but I want to use it more. if I should do certain things because it is handy or I made a mistake in giving information or setting up this question then please tell me so since I do want to use this correctly and want to help other in the end as well.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Guess what `statistics = {}` did.

Comment: I swear on my life that I removed that and it still didn't work but it does now..... I feel dumb but also freed haha. thanks for mentioning it. it works like it should now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either rename the statistics dictionary, or alias the statistics module import.

**Solution One** - Rename the `statistics` `dict`:

```py
# statistics = {}
statistics_dict = {}
```

**Solution Two** - Alias the `statistics` module (not recommended):

```py
# import statistics
import statistics as stats
```